# Syntax quirk on assigning a string with parentheses to a variable within an IF block

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Below is a BAT file sample which shows a curious behaviour. When a "SET" is used inside () an IF statement we get an error, if we have other code besides a SET then no problem.

I created a work around by doing the SET on the IF line and doing the other logic I need in a normal
`IF` ... `(` stuff `) ELSE (` more `)`

Does someone know what is going on here?

NB: Same outcome if SETLOCAL is used

```
::SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo **This works**
@set InstallerTest=false
@IF "%InstallerTest%"=="true" @SET SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signtrue.exe
@IF NOT "%InstallerTest%"=="true" @SET SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signfalse.exe
SET SESign_Exe

ECHO **THIS PRODUCES NO ERROR** 
@IF "%InstallerTest%"=="true" (
    echo IN TRUE PART
) ELSE (
    ECHO IN FALSE PART
)

echo **this produces : \Schneider was unexpected at this time.**
@IF "%InstallerTest%"=="true" (
    SET SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signtrue.exe
) ELSE (
    SET SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signfalse.exe
)
::ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: `SET "SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signtrue.exe"`

Comment: Yes this works! thanks, any idea why of is this just a quirk in the BATCH handling ?

Comment: You are in parenthesis context. In that context an un-escaped, un-quoted `)` have a special meaning of closing parenthesis context. And value of `ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variable have an `)` in it.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now that it was the data in the string, not the syntax. Don't seem to be able to flag as answer.

Comment: @GregBRoberts Never hurts to use parentheses around all your SET commands.  I try to make a habit of it. `set "var=cat and dog"`

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and execute there `cmd /?`. At bottom of the last help page output into the console window you can read which characters in strings require surrounding double quotes: the space character and `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

The reason is easy to understand. The space character is the separator for the "words" (commands, options, parameters, keywords, ...) on command line.

The other characters have special meanings in Windows command line syntax. A not escaped and not in quoted string defined `(` marks beginning of a block an `)` marks end of a block if not escaped or within a quoted string.

Therefore you need

```
set "SESign_Exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Schneider Electric\CodeSign\signtrue.exe"
```

And you should really use always `set "variable=value"`.

See for example answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for an explanation with an example why using `set "variable=value"` is always better than using just `set variable=value`.